# Компиляция классов Java без перезапуска контейнера сервелетов Jetty

Tags: java, jetty

Есть проект на Java, который запускается с помощью контейнера сервелетов Jetty в Eclipse. Если поменять класс в файле .java, то пока он не скопилирован, изменения не видны, так как файле .class еще нет изменений. Приходится делать перезапуск, в окне Debug. Можно ли компилировать только измененный класс без перезапуска Jetty, чтобы в Jetty попали выполненные изменения?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Если поменять класс в файле .java, то пока он не скопилирован,
>   изменения не видны, так как файле .class еще нет изменений.

Все куда хоже, даже откомпелированный класс не будет загружен в JVM, если он уже был загружен ранее, т.е. без рестарта JVM изменения не ведны. Есть проекты, которые решают данную проблему:

- [Spring-Loaded](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded#readme) - работает с любым проектом на JVM;
- [Play](https://www.playframework.com/) - Это фреймворк, который обновляет классы на лету;
- [Ninjaframework](http://www.ninjaframework.org/) - тоже фреймфорк, который решает проблему путем рестарта jetty (так на заметку).
- [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/features/) - java profiler тоже умеет рестартить классы, но он платный.

Также у Tomcat есть возможность указать перезакрузку контекса(веб-приложения):

```
<Context reloadable="true">
```

Загружает изменненые классы из `/WEB-INF/classes` и `/WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: есть еще хот свап без каких-либо перезагрузок http://hotswapagent.org/

Comment: @etki Точно, забыл. У меня как-то с ним не сложилось.